# i have cod i use to open a new window resizable using a text link but not if i try to use an image

Tags: javascript, html

i have been using this open an window using text

```
<p align="center">
    <a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://anyplace.com','shoping','resizable,height=1500,width=800'); return false;">
        <font size="3">shop now</font>
    </a>
</b>
<noscript>You need Javascript to use the previous link or use <a href="https://www.anywebsite.com" target="_blank">tses</a></noscript>
```

i would like to work on when they click on product image

Answer (score 0):

Apply a tag to your photo instead of the text of the shop now :

```
<p align="center">
<a href="#" onClick="window.open('https://anyplace.com','shoping','resizable,height=1500,width=800'); return false;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250" />
</a>
```